# php echo image from mysql not showing

Tags: php

Hi when im trying to display an image using php and mysql it only apears as the default no image found image is there anything im doing wrong here. i read a couple of different tutorials but they all seem to work where as my way does not

```
function DisplayImages($link){
    $qry = mysqli_query($link,"select * from images");
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    echo $row["name"];
    echo '<img src="<?php echo $row["image"]"/>';
    }
}
```

the images are uploaded as longblobs

Comment: Surely you need to at least convert it to a data url.

Comment: It could be a base64 image.

Comment: try something like that : 
` $image_resource = imagecreatefromstring($row["name"]);

 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
 imagejpeg($image_resource);`

Comment: yes i belive i do i guess the tutorials i was looking at are wrong. any idea how to do that?

Comment: echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '" />';    i can use this but it will only display the jpegs

Comment: nvm is also works for png

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not recursively embeddable:

```
echo '<img src="<?php echo $row["image"]"/>';
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're ALREADY in "PHP mode", so that `<?php` is not the start of a new PHP code tag. It's just the characters `<`, `?`, etc... being stuffed into the string you're echoing.

And even if this COULD work, you have no `?>` so it'd be a syntax error anyways.

Try:

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['image'] . '">';
or
echo "<img src=\"{$row['image']}\">";
```

If you'd done even basic debugging, like doing a "view source" in your browser to check the HTML you're building, you'd have seen that "php code" in your browser, meaning it never got executed.

Comment: hmm just appears as random symbols ive been reading about converting it before displaying?

Comment: `src` is for a URL. you can't stuff the raw binary bytes of an image into it. If your DB data IS a blob of the image, you can't display it like that. Either convert to a data url, or do this in two stages `<img src="showimage.php?id=XXX">`, and then have that script pretty much literally just do `echo $row['image']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '" /height="50" width="50">';
```

thansk for the help it was weird that 3 tutorials i found all never mentioned of used the base54 thing but it works now thankyou